# Execute nested method calls from Method object

Tags: java, reflection

I need to make a call to following method -

```
testObj.getA().getB().getC().getD();
```

Above, testObj.getA() returns object A which has a method getB(), which returns object B that has method getC(), which returns object C and it has method getD().

How can I invoke it using reflection? If I try Method object as following -

```
Method m = testObj.getClass().getMethod("getA().getB().getC().getD(), null));
```

Above fails saying the method is not found. Any suggestions?

Comment: Get the `Method` for `getA`. Invoke it. Take the return value and use reflection to get a `getB` `Method` from it. Invoke it. Take its return value and use reflection to a `getC` `Method` from it, ad nauseam.

Comment: My suggestion is: don't do this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How would you handle such a case where you have to traverse multiple method to get to the value you need but need to execute it at runtime?

Comment: Some kind of recursive structure that does what I described above. But there must be a better way if you explain what your use case is in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

```
D d = (D)PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(testObj, "a.b.c.d");
```

See [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.nested).

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a method called `getA().getB().getC().getD()`, so it's no surprise you can't get it. You have four separate methods.

There's nothing stopping you from calling them all through reflection, but you have to treat it as four separate method calls (because it *is*):

```
TypeOfA a = testObj.getClass().getMethod("getA").invoke(testObj);
TypeOfB b = TypeOfA.class.getMethod("getB").invoke(a);
TypeOfC c = TypeOfB.class.getMethod("getC").invoke(b);
TypeOfD d = TypeOfC.class.getMethod("getD").invoke(c);
```

Comment: Thanks. This call is supposed to be passed from another place. Almost like a context and where to look for data within that context so I was hoping there is a direct way to call it as passed in parameter. I can certainly break it up and call as above.

Comment: It sounds like your real question this is "How do I evaluate an arbitrary expression." @JUG.   I personally like OGNL for such a purpose.